# How do I compile a CPP file with a C file?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I am trying to implement my pthread_create function. After searching online I found few examples but I could not compile them and run the code.
I have these 2 files, first one is pthread.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <signal.h>


int (*original_pthread_create)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) = NULL;

void load_original_pthread_create() {
    void *handle = dlopen("libpthread-2.15.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    char *err = dlerror();
    if (err) {
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    original_pthread_create = dlsym(handle, "pthread_create");
    err = dlerror();
    if (err) {
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
}
int my_pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) {
    if (original_pthread_create == NULL) {
        load_original_pthread_create();
    }
    printf("I am creating thread from my pthread_create\n");
    return original_pthread_create(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}
```

I compiled this using the below command and got a shared object named libpthread.so

> gcc pthread.c -o libmypthread.so -shared -fpic -ldl

Now the second file, main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *dummyThread(void *t)
{
    // just spin/sleep until done
    //std::cout<<"This thread ID is "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
    //long thID = (long) id;
    printf("thread Id is  pthread id is %lu\n", pthread_self());
    while(!done)
    {
        sleep(10);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    pthread_t ptid1, ptid2;
 
    int ret1 = my_pthread_create(&ptid1, NULL, dummyThread, NULL);
    int ret2 = my_pthread_create(&ptid2, NULL, dummyThread, NULL);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    printf ("Goodbye Cruel World!\n");
}
```

To compile this above code, I use a Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
RM=rm -f
CPPFLAGS=-g 
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17
LDFLAGS=-g -rdynamic
LDLIBS=-lpthread -ldl

SRCS=main.cpp
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))

all: tool

tool: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o tool $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)
```

when I run make, I get this following error:

> undefined reference to `my_pthread_create(unsigned long*, pthread_attr_t const*, void* (*)(void*), void*)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/hgovindh/perf/main.cpp:: undefined reference to` my_pthread_create(unsigned long*, pthread_attr_t const*, void*
> (*)(void*), void*)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make:
> *** [Makefile:16: tool] Error 1

Now, how do I run this main.cpp so that it calls the my_pthread_create defined in the pthread.c file?

Comment: Why is it `cpp` in the first place? The code has nothing C++ specific in it, it looks like pure C (except includes syntax).

Comment: @EugeneSh. eventually there will be C++ specific code will be included. For now, I need to test whether I can call my custom pthread_create from this main.cpp file..

Comment: Just use 2 different variables and 2 rules for compiling `.c` and `.cpp` files to `.o` files or simply go with cmake which makes this choice for you based on the file extension in addition to allowing you to use build systems other than Unix makefiles...

Comment: @fabian, can you please explain how? with some command examples?

Comment: Your `main.cpp` [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/M6898qxP1). Please post a [mcve]. This also entails removal of irrelevant `#include` directives. The aim is to provide the *smallest possible* program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am unable to compile the main.cpp file. It throws the mentioned error.

Comment: And by the way you are trying to `dlsym` a function named `my_pthread_create` out of `"libpthread-2.15.so"`. I don't think it will work.

Comment: yeah just noticed that and changed the dlsym to dlsym(handle, "pthread_create");

Comment: `int my_pthread_create` -- When you compiled your .cpp module, that `int my_pthread_create(` became a mangled name.  Are you linking the compiled .c module with the .cpp module?  If so, that seems to be an issue due to the name mangling.

Comment: You built a (shared) library containing the wanted function, but you did not tell `g++` to link that library to your executable.  You can probably get it to link successfully by adding the shared library filename to the compile / link command, between `$(OBJS)` and `$(LDLIBS)`.

Comment: Also, `g++` ought to be complaining about your attempt to call function `my_pthread_create()` when there is no in-scope declaration for that function.  The conventional way to deal with that would be to create a header for your library that contains an appropriate declaration, and to `#include` that into `main.cpp`.  Note that you will want ensure that when that header is parsed as C++, the function is declared to have C linkage (this will address the name mangling issue).

Comment: You should use option `-pthread` at compilation (both components), the usage of dlopen/dlsym can be dropped (I guess they came from some symbol hijacking example progam).

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with C++'s name mangling? In C, if you have a function named `foo` -- regardless of the arguments it receives -- the symbol in the .o file is called `foo`. In C++, the name is mangled to include type information. This is how you can engage in method name overloading based on different arguments.

In your include file, you need to use

```
 extern "C" {
 ....
 }
```

This tells the C++ compiler that the symbols inside those braces are C symbols, and don't name-mangle them.

It will actually look something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

With similar `ifdef` around the closing brace.

You should wrap your entire C .h file in this type of guard so it can be included in your C++ files. The other choice is to guard it when you include it, but it's better if you do the guard in the include file itself.

So you'll ultimately have something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void load_original_pthread_create();
int my_pthread_create(pthread_t *, const pthread_attr_t *, void *(*) (void *), void *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I created a header file Header1.h with the above contents and included in the main.cpp as #include"Header1.h". 
But I still face the same undefined reference to my_thread_create error.
Is there any thing I am missing here?

Comment: `tool: $(OBJS) libmypthread.so`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do create different compilation rules depending on the file extension. Note that my preferred approach of using cmake is presented at the end of the answer.

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
RM=rm -f
CPPFLAGS=-g 
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17
CFLAGS=-g
LDFLAGS=-g -rdynamic
LDLIBS=-lpthread -ldl

SRCS=main.cpp pthread.c
OBJS=$(addsuffix .o,$(SRCS))

all: tool

tool: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o tool $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $<

%.c.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

this appends the `.o` to the file name including extension to be able to tell `.c` files appart from `.c` files in the rules for the `.o` file.

#### Alternative: Let CMake generate the makefiles

CMake can take care of generating the project files for you. It will automatically choose some reasonable defaults and allows you to change the build system you're using without much effort e.g. to ninja instead of unix makefiles.

**CMakeLists.txt**

(Place in the directory containing the source files)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
# compile features for c++17 only documented in v 3.16, but may be available earlier

project(Tool)

add_executable(tool
    main.cpp
    pthread.c
)

# make sure at least C++17 is used
target_compile_features(tool PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

set_target_properties(tool PROPERTIES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS Off # no -std=gnu-...
    # CXX_STANDARD 17 # require an exact standard (remove target_compile_feature, if commented in)
)

target_link_libraries(tool PRIVATE pthread ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Building the project on linux should use `gcc` and `g++` as default, unless you modified the environment variables to point to other compilers, in addition to using the generator "Unix Makefiles" by default.

Choose the name of a directory where CMake is free to modify/remove/overwrite any files without messing with your project files. I use `build_release` and `build_debug` below. From the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file, execute the following commands to create makefile projects for the release and debug version respectively. This step is necessary only once.

```sh
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S . -B build_debug
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B build_release
```

Now the equivalent of running make all would be

```sh
cmake --build build_debug
cmake --build build_release
```

(alternatively you could change the working directory to `build_debug` or `build_release` and run `make all`, but the `cmake --build ...` version works with any Generator type even without changing the working directory.)